# how to programmatically select the file in OpenFile dialog using C#

Tags: c#, .net, file, windows-10, pinvoke

I'm automating a small process of downloading a file using C#.

On a button click event, OpenFile dialog opens up. Now I want to programmatically select specified file and `SendKeys` to "open" button of dialog box.
Is it possible to do it using PInvoke? If yes, small example would be easy for me understand.

Comment: If you know the file you want to open… why use the open file dialog?

Comment: I'm trying to be polite, but can you proof read your question real quick and add some examples of what you've tried so far so we can better help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to automate the file selection in OpenFile dialog using PInvoke then you can try the below code and it should work.

```
SendKeys.SendWait("FilePath");
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: i was looking for this only. thanks i worked for me.